# How to transfer System Time's integer month to string month via Assembly 8086?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

So I have my code written in Assembly 8086 that asks for the system's current time,
(hours, minutes, seconds, day, month and year) but instead of previewing the current month of May which is the number "5" I want to output the month to String which from 
current date: 5/11/2014 to current date: May/11/2014? Should I use loops?

```
name "datefile"

org 100h  

TAB EQU 9   ; ASCII CODE

mov ah, 2ah                  ; get date 
int 21h 
xlat

mov week, al                 ; 0=sunday  
add cx, 0f830h               ; for years 
mov ax, cx 
call deci 

mov year, ax 
mov al, dh                   ; month 
call deci

mov mont, ax 
mov al, dl                   ; day 
call deci 
mov day, ax 


mov ah, 2ch                  ; get time 
int 21h 
mov al, ch                   ; hour 
call deci

mov hour, ax 
mov al, cl                   ; minute 
call deci

mov minu, ax 
mov al, dh                   ; second 
call deci

mov seco, ax 


mov ah, TAB 
mov dx, offset txt 
int 21h 


mov ax, 4200h 
xor cx, cx                   ; begin byte 0 
xor dx, dx                   ;  
int 21h 
jb error 




mov ah, 3eh                 ; close file.
int 21h 



; wait for any key press:
mov ah, 0
int 16h

error:                       ; leave program (unconditionally). 
mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h


deci:                        ; calculate in decimal 
push cx
xor ah, ah 
mov cl, 10 
div cl 
add ax, 3030h
pop cx
ret 



; here's data to display the date and time 

txt  db 0Dh, 0Ah, 0Ah, TAB, TAB          ; jump line and go two tabs right 
dat  db "date: "
week db 0, TAB                           ; put the day 1=monday   9 jump a colon (tab)
     db "20"
year db 0, 0, '-'        
mont db 0, 0, '-'
     ;db 0Ax, 

day  db 0, 0, TAB  


hour db 0, 0, ':'       
minu db 0, 0, ':' 
seco db 0, 0, ' '
     db 0Dh, 0Ah, 24h         ; line feed   return   and  stop symbol 24h=$ (ASCII). 

January:
    mov ax, OFFSET mont
    mov dh, ax                ; put month to 16 bit reg
    db "1 - January"
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to create 12 strings in .data part and then cmp using the values. like for example

```
cmp al,1 
je label 

label:
    mov ah,09h
    mov dx,offset january 
    int 21h .
```

This would be easy i think.
Its upto you how you create logic and implement it.

Comment: Just a question, how can I compare values above 10?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than loops, use a constant array.

```
Jan db "January$"
Feb db "January$"
...
Dec db "December$"

Months dw offset Jan
    dw offset Feb
    ...
    dw offset Dec
```

And then use month number to pick the right month

```
;Assuming SI contains zero-based month number
mov dx,  [Months+2*si] ;DX has now the offset of the month name
```